# google play services missing import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;

Tags: android

I am using ubuntu 14.04, i am trying upload file to google drive using google play services.

[I took help from here:-](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)

[Using this quickstart project from Github:-](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)

But google play services missing import:-

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
```

I am doing this way:-

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;

/**
 * Android Drive Quickstart activity. This activity takes a photo and saves it
 * in Google Drive. The user is prompted with a pre-made dialog which allows
 * them to choose the file location.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, 
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "android-drive-quickstart";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

    /**
     * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
     */
    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
        final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;

        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                        // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do
                        // anything
                        // and must
                        // fail.
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                            return;
                        }
                        // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                        // Get an output stream for the contents.
                        OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents()
                                .getOutputStream();
                        // Write the bitmap data from it.
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                                bitmapStream);
                        try {
                            outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                        }
                        // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                        // Note that the user will be able to change the title
                        // later.
                        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
                                .setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
                        // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                                .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                                .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                                .setInitialDriveContents(
                                        result.getDriveContents())
                                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                        try {
                            startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender,
                                    REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Please any one have this answer please help me.

Thanks in Advance:-

Comment: Have you added google play lib service to your workspace too?

Comment: Yaa i have import google play service to my project but it showing error for DriveContentsResult..

Comment: While you are importing it have you enabled `Copy to Workspace` checkbox??

Comment: Then while you have reference that libs to your project then it is with red mark or green mark?

Comment: yes that all works perfectly...but it showing error just for drive.DriveContentsResult.

Comment: So there is some mistake while imported. May be you imported wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and re-importing google-play-services-lib fixed it.